# The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly in drools.net

Tags: c#

Issue Details :

```
Main Exception :  Message: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
```

We have project- called "A.dll" that internally loads the Drools .net assembly for processing, the code is like below ,

```
"RuleBase RuleBase = RuleBaseLoader.LoadFromReader(RulesReader)"
```

Now this is working fine in the project A, now i take this dll ie "A.dll" and use it in another project ie "B.dll" form this project when i call that method it works fine.

Note :

The above scenario works fine in VisuslStudio but fails when i deploy to IIS.
Pls find beloe the complete exception details.

Please let me know if i have to follow any steps to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the dll's those are related to Drools (business rule engine) to the bin/virtual directory?